# Exception handeling in Flow.Interview.createInterview().start()

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, error-messages, gack

I have a Use case where I am starting a `Flow` execution from `Apex` as part of managed package and the actual flow is developed by our customer.

While testing I noticed that one of the flow is invoking an apex class and the invocable class throws an Aurahandled Exception in some cases.

As a best practice I have wrapped the `interview.start` in a try catch block but the exception message is a generic one and not the one which is thrown from the flow invocable class.

```
try {
    Map<String, Object> flowParameters = new Map<String, Object>{ 'key' => 'value' };
    Flow.Interview.createInterview('namespace', 'flowName', flowParameters).start();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    String message = ex.getMessage();
    // message: Flow handler failed with error: An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow 
    // An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow.
    // Please contact your system Administrator for more information
}
```

> Is there a way to get the exact error message from the flow?

Comment: Try listening to `FlowExecutionErrorEvent` from a Platform event based flows and check, as I am not sure how this event works in managed package  environment.